# How to get a storage file from camera roll in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-dev-center

How can I create a Windows.Storage.StorageFile from a picture in Camera Roll for windows phone 8.1? I have tried the follwing:-

```
try{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.CameraRoll;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
   }
   catch(Exception exc) 
   {
      MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
   }
```

Which is producing an Access Violation Exception.
Can someone plz tell me how to do it in windows phone 8.1?

Comment: What's the value of `filename`?

Comment: filename is a string. but, the exception is being thrown at the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may need to declare the capability in the package.appxmanifest.
[image]

Once you’ve done this you can now use the [Windows.Storage.KnownFolders class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to access the Picture Library.

Here is how to get to the camera roll, you can refer to.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> GetFilesInCameraRoll()
```

{
    var cameraRoll = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("Camera Roll");

```
return await cameraRoll.GetFilesAsync();
```

}

More detailed information, you can refer to [Access Camera Roll in Windows Phone 8.1](http://jshapland.com/access-camera-roll-in-windows-8-1-universal-app/)